# Creating an event that triggers when a List is updated

Tags: c#, list, observer-pattern

I've got a static class (DataFormSubject) that holds a generic List object, as follows:

```
private static List<DataForm> dataForms = new List<DataForm>();
```

Other classes that rely on this list need to be told when the list is updated, so I created a custom event, and associated methods that could trigger when an item is added or removed, as follows:

```
    public delegate void DataFormsUpdatedHandler(object sender);
    public static event DataFormsUpdatedHandler DataFormsUpdatedEvent;

    public static void AddDataForm(DataForm df)
    {
        dataForms.Add(df);
        if (DataFormsUpdatedEvent != null)
            DataFormsUpdatedEvent(df);
    }

    public static void RemoveDataForm(DataForm df)
    {
        dataForms.Remove(df);
        if (DataFormsUpdatedEvent != null)
            DataFormsUpdatedEvent(df);
    }
```

The List is available from the static class via a property, as follows:

```
   public static List<DataForm> DataForms
    {
        get { return dataForms; }
        //set { dataForms = value; }
    }
```

But the problem here is that the client can now *bypass* the update event by accessing the property and doing a direct add or remove on the class! E.g.

```
     DataFormSubject.DataForms.Add(new DataForm);
```

How can I prevent this, or is there a better way of acheiving what I want? Ideally what I would like is an update event on the List class that observers can subscribe to!

Comment: As an aside - *anything* that involves static events (direct or indirect) is likely to cause problems. You'll need to be **very** strict about unsubscribing, otherwise you'll keep all your objects alive and run out of memory.

Comment: I'm not that happy about using a static class for this either, but how else can I maintain a single collection that can be accessed throughout my application without passing the collection fromobject to object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider using `BindingList<T>` or `ObservableCollection<T>`; both of these do what you want in standard ways.

You cannot do anything interesting by subclassing `List<T>` - the methods aren't virtual. `Collection<T>` is designed to be more extensible, but in this case everything you need is already provided (by `BindingList<T>`).

In particular, this provides:

- [IBindingList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.ibindinglist.aspx) (used by many UI binding components, such as grids)
- [ListChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132742.aspx) - that your code can subscribe to for detailed notification

Answer (score 2):

You want to look into using an `ObservableCollection` for such a purpose. See [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748365.aspx) to get started.

Answer (score 0):

Don't show an IList from the static class, only show an Enumerable:

```
public static IEnumerable<DataForm> DataForms
{
    get { return dataForms; }
    //set { dataForms = value; }
}
```

This way all changes must be done through your class

Comment: The static class has the notification event.